# Android - how to properly design and instantiate classes outside activity in order to access ctx/activity?

Tags: java, android, oop

My applications is getting big.

In order to make it robust, I decided to split it into seperate classes outside the activity, each representing a set of activity functionalities.

The problem is, I often need context/activity variables in these classes.

Which creates confusion for me:

Should I "extend" the MainActivity class and then use the parents() get context/actvitiy methods, or should I instantiate each of the classes with Context/Activity variables like this:

```
static private BrowseHandler instance;

static public void init(Context ctx, FragmentActivity ac) {
    if (null==instance) {
        instance = new BrowseHandler(ctx, ac);
    }
}
static public BrowseHandler getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

Which approach is better?

Or perhaps, have I missed the whole point? Should I keep my activities code inside my Activity?

Comment: Aside, related: I've found that Android doesn't separate the "view" and "controller" responsibilities as well as the other mobile platforms, with Activities and ListAdapters ending up chock full of low level view-manipulation code. If this is your problem, try creating dedicated View classes. If you have e.g. the child view of a ListView and its root tag is RelativeLayout, just subclass RelativeLayout, make your subclass the root tag, and move all the low-level view manipulation into the subclass. Your listadapter can cast its inflated view to the correct type and call high level methods on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the `Context` in a static field. A static variable is shared by all instances of the class, so putting the context in a static variable reduce the reusability of your class since it will be usable only in one context. (the context that was used to iniatialize the static field).

Instead, pass the context as a method argument when you are calling code that is not in an Activity.

Regarding your idea of extending the MainActivity... it seems a strange pattern. How are going to instanciate it ?

```
new MyExtendedMainActivity(this);
```

There is no real added value to extend MainActivity. There is only drawback : you cannot extend something else. Additionally, you will have Activity objects that aren't handeld by the android OS. Remember that in android you never instantiate an activity yourself : the android framework do it for you and you only have callbacks to configuring it.

Comment: Agreed, passing it as a method argument is the easiest way to get this right. Holding on to "managed" classes such as Activity from unmanaged classes is error-prone and best avoided entirely.

Comment: But I haven't showed Context variable in my snippet. My context is not static. Can you comment the part about "extending" MainActivity and why that wouldn't work?

Comment: the browserHandler is static and reference the Context (since it is a constructor arg, I assume it is also an instance variable of the singleton BrowserHandler)